# TypeORM Error: "item" alias was not found. Maybe you forgot to join it?

Tags: left-join, query-builder, typeorm

I would like to create this SQL using typeorm queryBuilder

```
SELECT * FROM `item-stats` LEFT JOIN item ON item.itemStatsId = `item-stats`.id WHERE item.state = 'Active' LIMIT 1
```

My code is:

```
await getConnection()
            .getRepository(ItemStatsEntity)
            .createQueryBuilder('itemStats')
            .leftJoin('item.itemStatsId', 'itemStatsId', 'itemStatsId = itemStats.id') 
            .orderBy('subjectCharCnt', 'DESC') 
            .getOne();
```

But I am getting an error:

```
Error: "item" alias was not found. Maybe you forgot to join it?
```

What is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 1):

You should specify the alias in `createQueryBuilder`

```
   await getConnection()
                .getRepository(ItemStatsEntity)
                .createQueryBuilder('item') // you set the alias here
                .leftJoin('item.itemStatsId', 'itemStatsId', 'itemStatsId = itemStats.id') 
                .orderBy('subjectCharCnt', 'DESC') 
                .getOne();
```